# PushWoosh AIR ane on iOS : disable alert on iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, push-notification, pushwoosh

I'm using this PushWoosh AIR ANE : https://github.com/shaders/push-notifications-sdk/tree/master/SDK%20Sample%20Projects/AdobeAir/ANE-Pushwoosh/bin

When my devices receive a push notification while the app is in foreground, the PushWoosh SDK automatically display an alert with the notification content and two buttons : "Cancel" and "OK".

I did some research and found this in PushNotificationManager.h (PushWoosh iOS SDK) :

```
//show push notifications alert when push notification received and the app is running,    default is TRUE
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL showPushnotificationAlert;
```

Unfortunately, i could not find a way to set this parameter to FALSE using the ANE (in AS3).
So i figured i should compile the ANE myself.
I tried, but i didn't manage to do it. I have errors during compilation :

```
android/src/com/arellomobile/android/push/ADMRegistrar.java:32: error: package com.amazon.device.messaging does not exist
```

So i have two questions :

1) Is there any way to prevent the PushWoosh SDK from displaying an alert when receiving a push while the app is running in foreground OUTSIDE the SDK (using the remote API maybe? using the native extension?)

2) If the answer to 1) is no, how can i compile the ANE myself?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the issue has been resolved on github, so I post the link here:

https://github.com/shaders/push-notifications-sdk/issues/32

The new ANE has been committed to the github repo.
To control the alert add "Pushwoosh_SHOW_ALERT" key into Info.plist file with the boolean value YES or NO.

Thanks!

Pushwoosh team